# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_DRF'

Tags: python, django

I just running the django project for welcome, it come out the issue with No module named 'django_DRF'.

```
python==3.8
django==4.2
```

I have installed the djangorestframework and add rest_framework in INSTALLED_APPS, but i still have the same issue.

Thank you for help!!

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happened.  Please post the full error message.

Comment: It looks like something is using the wrong name `django_DRF`...

Comment: I have set the wrong enviroment variables when running the project it did't load the settings.

Answer (score 1):

if after installing and adding it to your INSTALLED_APPS it persist, then it's most likely because you're using `python3` to run the server and thats okay. So what you do while installing is use `python3 -m pip install djangorestframework`